# Integrate a partial derivative.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I have seen that $\int_{[a,b]}f'(x)=f(b)-f(a)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. But what is $\int_{\Omega}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$?

Comment: Split the integration as $dx = dx_1\dots\hat{dx_i}\dots dx_n \cdot dx_i$, integrate w.r.t. $dx_i$ first and use the one dimensional result that you know.

Comment: This is crazy vague. What is $\Omega$? You should also not omit the $dx$ or appropriate $d\mu$. It makes a huge difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Omega$ is smooth enough, then this is

$$
\int_{\partial\Omega} f(\sigma) \nu_i(\sigma) \,d \sigma
$$

where $\nu=(\nu_1,\ldots,\nu_N)$ is the outward pointing unit normal to $\partial\Omega$.